# Extensions to symplectomorphisms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $G$ be a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$.  Then the map $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ given by
$(x,0)\mapsto (G(x),0)$ may be extended to a symplectomorphism
$(x,\xi)\mapsto (G(x),(G')^{-1}(x)\xi)$ of $T^*\mathbb{R}$.  (Here, $(x,\xi)$ are symplectic coordinates in $T^*\mathbb{R}$.)

In other words, a map on the zero section of $T^*\mathbb{R}$, of the form given above (i.e., which is identifiable with a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}_x$), may be lifted to a symplectomorphism of the cotangent bundle.  (This could certainly be stated in higher dimensions, with $G'$ replaced by the Jacobian matrix of $G$.)

Now let $\mathcal{C} = \{\xi_1 = 0\}\subset T^*\mathbb{R}^2$.  We take $(x_1,\xi_1;x_2,\xi_2)$ as coordinates on $T^*\mathbb{R}^2$.  Suppose we start with the map $\Psi:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ given by
$(x_1,0;x_2,\xi_2)\mapsto (\varphi(x_1,x_2,\xi_2),0;x_2,\xi_2)$.  Here, $\varphi$ is differentiable in all three components and for each $(x_2,\xi_2)$,
$x_1\mapsto\varphi(x_1,x_2,\xi_2)$ is invertible.  $\Psi$ is a pre-symplectomorphism of the coisotropic submanifold $\mathcal{C}$, with respect to the form $d\xi_2\wedge dx_2$.  Think of $\varphi$ as a diffeomorphism of $x_1$ depending smoothly on $(x_2,\xi_2)$: $\varphi(x_1,x_2,\xi_2) = G_{(x_2,\xi_2)}(x_1)$.  My question is: Can $\Psi$ be extended to a symplectomorphism of $T^*\mathbb{R}^2$?  That is: Does there exist a symplectomorphism $\Phi$ of $T^*\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\Phi|_\mathcal{C} = \Psi$?

A first attempt would be
$\Phi:(x_1,\xi_1;x_2,\xi_2)\mapsto (G_{(x_2,\xi_2)}(x_1),(G'_{(x_2,\xi_2)})^{-1}(x_1)\xi_1;x_2,\xi_2)$, where the prime indicates differentiation in the $x_1$ variable.  But this isn't a symplectomorphism.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative already at infinitesimal level. If your extension was possible, then the Jacobian matrix would be in general an upper triangular block matrix (with 2x2 blocks).
And it is easy to check that such a matrix can never be symplectic, unless it is a diagonal block matrix: Indeed, if we denote $J=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, if 
$$\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\0&C\end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}J&0\\0&J\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\0&C\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}J&0\\0&J\end{pmatrix}$$
then $A^TJA=J$, $C^TJC=J$ (i.e. $A$ and $C$ are symplectic) and $B^TJA=0$ which implies $B=0$.
So I think, your map can be extended only if $\phi$ only depends on $x_1$

Comment: It isn't so obvious to me that every upper triangular block matrix which is symplectic must be a diagonal block matrix.  Could you please explain this?

Comment: Sorry, it was a bit quick. I added some details to the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  But isn't $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ a symplectic matrix?

Comment: It is indeed symplectic but not of the form $\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\0&C\end{pmatrix}$ with $A$, $B$ and $C$ 2x2 matrices.

Comment: I don't see why this should be true only for 2x2 blocks (or blocks larger than 1x1).

Comment: Well, in the argument that I give in my answer, it is important that the matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$ are 2x2, because the matrix $J$ is itself 2x2.

Comment: So do you believe this extension is possible for $n\times n$ blocks for $n>2$?

Comment: Is there a generalization of your argument to $\begin{pmatrix}J & 0 \\ 0 & J\end{pmatrix}$, where $J$ is of size $n\times n$?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I see now that only in the case $n=1$ can an upper triangular, symplectic matrix not be diagonal.

Comment: How do you know that $B^T J A = 0$ implies $B = 0$?  $A$ isn't assumed to be invertible, is it?  Thanks.

Comment: You said that if such an extension (to a symplectomorphism) existed, the Jacobian matrix of the extension would be upper triangular, in general.  But are there exceptional cases where the Jacobian is non-triangular and hence possibly symplectic?  (Sorry for all the comments.)

Comment: A is invertible since it is symplectic.